# mysql querying a utf charset table for c returns ç

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I managed to insert special characters into a table by setting the charset with

```
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thing is, when I run the following query on the table

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word = 'francais';
```

it returns both "francais" and "français"!

This is not quite desirable for my situation.. I have no idea why it does this because they're just different...

Can anyone tell me how to avoid this? Would be much appreciated.

lordstyx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using collation, e.g.,

```
select *
from table
where word = 'francais' collate utf8_bin;
```